# Need to reload the same page so that the apex gets called again

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, redirect

I am overriding the Lead Convert functionality with a Visualforce page.
Using custom extensions for the same. The functionality of the custom extension has been developed in such a way that, in the method, there is an if-else scenario, if being executed when everything goes fine, while else is being used up to show the error message to the users.

My requirement is to not to show any error message to the users. So whenever we enter in the else part, I want that I redirect back to the same vf page which called my apex method, and the same method be executed back again.

What I've done so far is creating a new PageReference and provided the URL of my Visualforce page again, but the on-load function of JavaScript is not calling the `apex:actionFunction` to call that apex method again.

Can anyone Please provide any suggestion on that?

VF Code :

```
<apex:form >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load(){
            recalc();
        }
        window.onload=load;
    </script>
    <apex:actionFunction name="recalc" 
        action="{!checkContvertAndRedirect}" 
        reRender="test"/>
```

Apex code for else part:

```
else {
    System.debug('>>>>Entered in else>>>>');
    //relatedListsNotFetched = 'NA';
    //errorMsg = 'Something went Wrong. Please Try Again Later.';
    return new PageReference('/apex/tdc_tlc__SingleLeadConvert?id='+lead.id+'&statusid=reloaded');

}
```

Comment: Hi Shobhit, have you thought about the scenario where the conversion failed for a valid reason? This will cause the user to end up in an infinite loop of being referred back to the VisualForce page.

Comment: Hi Koen, we have tested this functionality thoroughly, and the lead is getting converted at all possible situations. Here the else part is for handling some other feature during lead conversion, in which for exceptional cases, the Lead is not getting converted efficiently at the first time, but after retrying at a later time, it gets converted.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have *script*-tags **inside** your *apex:form*-tags, I believe. Also, you should probably be using an event listener instead of *window.onload*.

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        recalc();
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        load();
    });
</script>    

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="recalc" 
        action="{!checkContvertAndRedirect}" 
        reRender="test"/>
```